# Setup language pack for Magento

Tags: magento

I am using Magento to create own shop. I have created all functionality in English. Now I want to install Russian language pack. I want to setup configs for language pack. Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a language pack here http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-russian-language-pack-russkij-perevod-ver-1-8-h-i-bolee-rannih.html

and set it up like this http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/adding-a-new-language-in-magento/

Comment: Thanks, I have done this part, but when I choose language from frontend the labels (e.g. My Account, Login, etc) are not translating